# Selenium webdriver : How to display values in console (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm using *selenium webdriver with node.js (javascript )*
Is there any way **to output some value in the test runtime console**.

Something like :

```
console.log(variable)
```

but in the console of the test while running .

**Suggestions ?**

Comment: Have you tried using the apache Log4j module?

Comment: no i haven't  , but if it is usable , just tell me how to use it

Comment: Here is the link for your reference - https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/download.html

Comment: log4j is used for java logging . question is about javascript

Comment: yeah am looking for javascript

Comment: Are you looking to display the stacktrace? or what information? I think console.log would do the work. Otherwise you need to give a proper example of what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are looking for some inbuilt function similar to,

```
System.out.print("");  //Java
```

In JS if we need to print something to the console,try this

```
console.log("");
```

The above code will simply show the output in the output console. Proceed down if you need to write the logs in a separate text file.

In order to write the logs in a text file we can use the log4js library which requires node.

1). Download the log4js library

```
npm install -g log4js //global installation
```

2). Now use this in your selenium script.

Below is a example java script which uses log4js to create a log file/append.

```
var log4js = require('log4js');
log4js.loadAppender('file');
log4js.addAppender(log4js.appenders.file('logs/runlog.log'), 'cheese');

var logger = log4js.getLogger('cheese');

logger.info('Clicked on the Submit button successfully');
logger.error('Not able to find the submit button');
```

This will show the messages in the output console and appends the messages in the available/created file "logs/runlog.log". The logged messages are colourfull depending upon the logged level(info/warn).

For more information regarding the log4js refer this=>[JS logger - log4js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/log4js)

Comment: not  logging to client inteface , logging to testing console

Comment: @firasKoubaa the question was not clear for me. Now i have updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you're looking at displaying a stacktrace or just want to print something in your document. As far as I am concerned, I am using the `console.log()` method to print out something during the tests in the terminal and it works perfectly fine.

I'm using Jasmine with Protractor, and we have a very good `jasmine-spec-reporter` library  which allows printing a stack trace in decent formatted version. You can refer this [git](https://github.com/zac11/jasmine_spec_reporter) here. Not sure if this is gonna work with `nodejs` though.